# Illegal Expression on Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

```
program latihan;
uses crt;

var
    a, b, c : integer;
    d : real;

begin
    write('a: ');
    readln(a);
    write('b: ');
    readln(b);
    c := a + b;
    d := a + b;
    sqr(c);
    writeln(c);
    sqrt(d);
    writeln(d:0:0);
end.
```

why there's an illegal expression at code `sqrt(d)` ??

what is the explanation why there can be an illegal expression at the `sqrt(d)` code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

The sqrt() function in Pascal only works on integer types, while d is a real type. So trying to pass a real value to sqrt() results in an illegal expression error.

To fix this, you need to use a different square root function that supports real numbers, such as:

```pascal
uses Math;

//...

sqrt(d);
```

Alternatively, you can convert d to an integer first before using sqrt():

```pascal
c := trunc(d);
sqrt(c);
```

Comment: Thankyouu for the answer, I'll give it a tryy.

Comment: `sqrt()` works perfectly fine on integer and real types. The return value, however,  needs to be assigned to a real type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You say: *The sqrt() function in Pascal only works on integer types*. AFAIK, `sqrt()` takes real types as well as integer types. Please, refer to doc that confirms your statement, or edit your answer.

Answer (score 3):

`sqrt()` is a *function* returning a value and needs to be used as that. You used it like a procedure.

Functions need their return value assigned to variables, like in

```
    c := sqrt (c);
```

The variable you assign the return value of `sqrt()` to needs to be a REAL type.

Answer (score 1):

`sqrt()` returns an Extended value, to receive the result you need to assign it to a variable, the same for `sqr()`:

```
c := sqr(c);
writeln(c);
d := sqrt(d);
writeln(d);
```